# How can I change Firefox theme when visiting some websites?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, css, styles, stylish

I'm using the [stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on for Mozilla Firefox for styling some elements in the browser using css.

Is there a way to test the URL so these customs styles can be applied only when I visit a chosen website ?

Or is there any other option to achieve that goal ?

Comment: You mean like `@-moz-document url(http://www.example.com/test.html)`?

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish/wiki/Applying-styles-to-specific-sites)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately it seems that I can't acces the browser element such as `.tabbrowser-tab .tab-label` in the `@-moz-document` tag. It does work outside this tag.